# What are the best methods to create migrations on an already started project?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-migrations

I have a medium sized project in my hands, with about 20 models, some many2many fields. I tried with --fake, recreating the migrations, deleting django_migrations etc etc. Every time I have problems involving existing fields. Obviously I can't delete the data inside, but I find myself unable to add a field or share the code because all my collaborators obviously have different migrations. Do you know methods to apply on an already started project?

Comment: You should not delete `django_migrations`. What is the problem with just `makemigrations`? This takes into account the old state of the models, and will thus create new columns, etc. Not remove the old tables.

Comment: thanks for the reply @WillemVanOnsem, but my colleagues have migrations that depend on other migrations, meaning I have 0001-app and my colleague may have it but different with different dependencies, our migrations are not aligned at the moment.

Comment: Everyone should be using the same migrations, your migrations should be committed to whatever VCS you store your code in.

Comment: @Plaoo: you should work with a proper subversioning system and updated regularly such that there are no name clashes.

Comment: Hi @JimmyPells , I know... But this was not the case, my question is this, is it possible to realign everyone?

Comment: Delete all migrations in your migrations folder, create new initial migration "makemigrations", commit migrations to your VCS, I would recommend rebuilding your development database from scratch but you said that was not a possibility so.... truncate django_migrations table, fake apply your new initial migrations